# conversion of string to const char*

Tags: c++, string, char

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <mysql.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
MYSQL* conn;
MYSQL_ROW row;
MYSQL_RES* res;

int qstate; 

conn = mysql_init(0);
if(conn) //if succeeded
    cout << "connection object ok" << endl;
else
    cout << "conn object problem" << mysql_error(conn) <<endl;

conn = mysql_real_connect(conn,"localhost","root","","ascii_table",0,NULL,0);
 if(conn) //if succeeded
 {
   cout << "connection to database ok" << conn << endl;

   string message = "";

    cout << "Enter message:" <<endl;
    getline(cin,message);

    qstate = mysql_query(conn,"select * from datatable");

   if(qstate!=0) //means nonzero
   {

  cout <<mysql_error(conn);
  return 1;
   }
      else{
       res = mysql_store_result(conn);
       const char* c;

     while (row=mysql_fetch_row(res)){
            for(int i=0; i<message.size(); i++){
            string character(1,message[i]);
            c = character.c_str();
            if(c==row[4]){
        cout << "Decimal " << row[0] << "\t";
        cout << "Octal "  << row[1] << "\t";
        cout << "Hexadecimal " << row[2] << "\t";
        cout << "Binary "  << row[3] << "\t";
        cout << "\n";
            }
     }
      }
      }//end else
 }
else{
    cout << "conn object problem" << mysql_error(conn) <<endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

My problem is now here:

```
 const char* c;

 while (row=mysql_fetch_row(res)){

        for(int i=0; i<message.size(); i++)
        {
        string character(1,message[i]);
        c = character.c_str();

        if(c==row[4]){
    cout << "Decimal " << row[0] << "\t";
    cout << "Octal "  << row[1] << "\t";
    cout << "Hexadecimal " << row[2] << "\t";
    cout << "Binary "  << row[3] << "\t";
    cout << "\n";
        }
 }
  }
```

I get no error when I run the code but the values of decimal,hexadecimal,octal and binary are not being displayed.What could be the problem.I thought maybe it is the conversion from string to const char* but am not sure.

Comment: Have you used the debugger of to see the values?

Comment: `if(c==row[4]){` this is doing pointer comparison and will only be true if `c` and `row[4]` point at the same *memory address*, but you'll likely want to compare their content instead.

Comment: @RvdK how do I do this??

Comment: `std::string` has an overload for `==` that compares with `const char*`. If you just use the `std::string` value in the comparison instead of calling its `c_str()`, I think it will work. I.e., `if (character == row[4]) {`

Comment: @lorrainemutheu use [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/), or just abandon c-style strings in favor for std::string.

Comment: @FredLarson I tried that but it did not work

Comment: @Please send me an example on how to use strcmp based on my code....I have checked the link you sent but I dont know how to apply

Comment: It _does_ work, so you did it wrong, and should try again because that is the better approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ben Steffan said, you are comparing pointer values and not the content as string.
You do not pass the "if(c==row[4])", so you are not printing your values.

In C there is strcmp to compare char pointers as string :
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/

You could also build string objects and compare them if you'd like but it will be less efficient.

Comment: @BenSteffan is this the correct use of strcmp.....(strcmp(c,row[4])!=0)

Comment: strcmp returns 0 when strings are equal, so in your case it should be :
 (strcmp(c,row[4])==0)